# Why does encode not work? (UTF-8, String, Java)

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, inputstream

I am executing a command by using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.de");
```

This returns a Process, which i take the inputstream from. Then i initialize a BuffredReader

```
BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processInputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

If i do

```
System.out.println(reader.readLine()); // The returned String of readLine()
// is used to create a javafx.scene.text.Text in my application
```

it will print '?' instead of characters like 'ü', 'ä' or 'ö'
so the sentence "This character - ä - wont work" is encoded to "This character - ? - wont work"
how to encode those things correct?

Thanks, Basti
ps: yes i know this question has been asked a few times, but i couldn't find a thread which could solve my case

Comment: It's the target where you print which messes it up. If you see one question mark per character you printed, then the multibyte UTF-8 codes were properly decoded into single characters.

Comment: What do you mean by target? idk where the wrong encoding happens. the inputstream of the process will only stream bytes. then inputstreamreader should be encoding them into uft-8, but it doesn't. the BufferedReader is only returning the characters until the system-lineseperator is found. is it the inputstreamreader which fails?

Comment: @McDowell i debugged into my readingmethod and readLine() already returns a String which contains the '?'. It is not the println()

Comment: @Basti: What operating system are you using? Windows? Linux? MacOS?

Comment: @Codo i am working on windows. but as you can see i am not using the default charset to encode the bytes of the inputstream. i set it to UTF-8. So it shouldn't matter on which operatingsystem my programm is running, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of an *InputStreamReader* specifies the encoding of the incoming byte stream so it can be properly converted into Java *String* instances, which are independent of the encoding. So it has to match the encoding of the command line environment where your commands are executed. In your case it's the encoding of your Windows command shell.

From my experience, the proper encoding in a Windows environment is likely "CP850".

```
BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processInputStream, "CP850"));
```

Comment: can i fix this by using System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); ?

Comment: if i use Charset.defaultCharset() as my encoding-charset, it doesn't work, too. still '?'

Comment: Did it work with "CP850"? `System.setProperty()` won't help as it sets the encoding of the Java environment and not of the Windows shell. `Charset.defaultCharset()` doesn't work either as it queries the encoding of the Java environment, which is usually the same as the underlying OS' encoding. But the command line shell on Windows has yet another encoding.

Comment: i didnt test cp850, because i am searching for a solution which works, no matter on which os my application is running

Comment: I'm afraid this an area where Java's operating independence ends. I doubt you can find solution that works without check for groups of operating systems.